# Which conjugation is this 生きていこう?

Tags: conjugations

I guess the title says it all. Which conjugation is this:

> 生きる  -> 生きていこう

?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

生きる + いく
so（生きる -> 生きて）+ （いく -> いこう）

Answer (score 2):

生きていこう = 生き(the 連用形/continuative form of the verb 生きる) + て(a 接続助詞/conjunctive particle) + いこ(the 未然形/imperfective form of the subsidiary verb いく) + う(a verbal auxiliary which means "will"). This is a grammar which native Japanese learn.

生きていこう = 生きて(the te-form of 生きる) + 行こう(the volitional form of the subsidiary verb いく) as chocolate-san says. This is a grammar for Japanese learners who learn Japanese as a second language.

> 生きていこう "Let's/I'll keep on living / go on living"

There seem to be different ways to analyze it.

Comment: Or, you could also analyze it this way: 生きていこう is the volitional form of 生きていく, "keep on living", which consists of 生きて(the te-form of 生きる) + subsidiary verb いく(行く)

Comment: 日本語教育の世界には連用形は存在しないそうです… http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36310/5010

Comment: I found a interesting webpage. http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1368071308

Comment: よく見たら、まだ和訳がなかったので入れてもいいですかね・・

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: 間違えた、和訳じゃなくて英訳だった :P

Answer (score -3):

生きていこう is 1. [ Let us / Let's ... ] form, or 2.  [ I will / shall ] form.

> http://www.geocities.jp/swadii228/bunkei/ikoukei.html
>
> 意向(いこう)形
>
> 1.  [ Let us ... ] -- ①  積極的(せっきょくてき)に相手を誘(さそ)う。 「～ましょう」の普通体
>
> 2.  [ I will / shall ] -- ②  これから自分が何かします、という気持ち。 自分の意志(いし)。 （ひとりで話すとき、心の中で言うとき）

---

Tense or Aspect

生きていこう -- It'd be possible to dream up a contrived situation in which 生きていこう means ( 生きて ) +  ( 行こう ) === meaning : Let's live (some more) and go to that place (again).

But 99% of the time, 生きていこう doesn't mean that.

99% of the time, it contains expression of the aspect  ［direction of time］ (＋intention).

<sub>Now, i'm not sure this should be called  （inchoative、起動相 動詞） -- Mr. Niwa does not use the term 起動相</sub>

> http://www.geocities.jp/niwasaburoo/24asupekuto.html 
> 24.8 Ｖ－ていく・てくる ［時間的な方向を示す場合］
>
> 変わっていく、 増えていく、 太ってくる、 暗くなってくる 
> 時代はどんどん変わっていきます。 
> この町もこれから発展していくでしょう。

＞ 新年 おめでとう御座います。 今年も張り切っていきましょう ！ 
＞ この会を盛り上げていこう。 今年も頑張って参ります ！！

以上のような例では、 空間的に「行く」のではなく、 100％［時間的な方向を示す］としか考えられません。

また、「調べていく」ですが、 「明日の訪問前に調べて参ります」 なら、 「調べて」から「行く」 ですね。

ネット上の検索では、［時間＋意思］の例 が多いように思えます。

- 貴社について調べていくうちに貴社で働きたいという気持ちが日に日に増していき、
- とりあえず好きなモノから調べていくと良いというお話 - RIZE
- 調べていけば調べていくうちに、あれもこの人だったのか ... - Naverまとめ
- いろいろ調べていくうちに、誰もが思う。「本当に稼げるのだろうか」

In these 4 usage examples of 「調べていく」, what is expressed is the
aspect of  ［direction of time］ (＋intention).

<sub>Probably ...,  in
「調べていく」, the intention is in the verb 「調べる」 only, and 「...ていく」 contains the  aspect of  ［direction of time］  only.</sub>