# Negative Present and Past Progressive

Tags: grammar

I have been looking into the negative form of progressive in japanese.

Sites such as japaneseverbconjugator don't give a conjugation for both of those if they are not in the polite form, which makes me wonder if they exist at all.

In short, in a neutral tone, is it ok to say :

- I am not eating  : 食べて**いない**　？
- I was not eating : 食べて**いなかった**　？
- he doesn't want a horse : 彼は馬を欲しが**っていない**　？
- he didn't want a horse : 彼は馬を欲しが**っていなかった**　？

I hope my question makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help !

Best,

W

Comment: So [this page](http://www.japaneseverbconjugator.com/VerbDetails.asp?txtVerb=%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%82%8B&Go=Conjugate) has weird blanks in the cells where 食べていない and 食べていなかった are expected. I think this is just a bug on their side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these sentences are all grammatical and make perfect sense. The number of possible "stacked" conjugations is very large (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61903/5010) for an example), so websites cannot show them all.

Comment: Thank you ! It was indeed my guess that they were just not written, but as a beginner it is always hard to really make sure what you think is actually correct. Thank you also for the precious resources !