# Japanese Name of the て-form without the て

Tags: grammar, conjugations, terminology

While reading [this old question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36310/does-te-form-of-a-verb-always-include-%E3%81%A6-%E3%81%A7-why), I began wondering what the て-form without the て (i.e.  書いて→書い、読んで→読ん、行って→行っ) is called in Japanese. Wikipedia calls it [2つ目の連用形](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8). Some other places call it 連用形の促音便形 or 連用形の撥音便形. I'm curious as to what teachers call this when they teach to kids as well as what it's called when discussed in research etc.

A related question is: 書かない→**書か**、書こう→**書こ** are both considered 未然形. Is there any way of disambiguating the two other than Wikipedia's 2つ目の未然形?

Comment: Well, with your second question, historically they were both the 書か form - 書かむ、書かう, 書こう was the progression I believe.

Comment: Sure, but I was wondering if there's a way people distinguish the two nowadays.

Comment: I think 音便形 or some variation thereof is what anyone trying to be clear would call it. Unfortunately I don’t know enough about Japanese education to be able to answer your question though.

Comment: I am completely sure I’ve seen the term 音便形. At least, it makes sense.