# How do you say 〜て form in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, suffixes, terminology

I’ve tried to google this but I end up with explanations about how to use the ーて form. I want to know how to call it in Japanese, you know, like a noun is 名詞, now do you call the ーて form in grammatical terms.

Answer (score 2):

It is called（動詞の）テ形.

Also, [品詞]{ひん・し} means "part of speech" which would help when you Google things like that.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Japanese people will not be familiar with this term unless they know about Japanese grammar education aimed at non-natives. Grammar resources for natives don't talk about テ形.

Comment: @Leebo how do they call it then?

Comment: @EtienneZizka て in Japanese grammar is considered a conjunction particle (接続助詞) which attaches to the conjunctive form of a verb (連用形), also called the masu stem form in English .

Comment: Thank you, I had not realised it was to be interpreted as a particle considering it’s not used independently as with は or を.

Comment: @EtienneZizka You may be interested in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36310/5010). I posted it when I did not know the te-form was a full-fledged conjugation form to a JSL learner. As a native speaker of Japanese, I always believed 見て was two words because that was how I learned at school.

Comment: Thank you, it’s pretty complicated but I’ll get it eventually.