# Who invented the te-form concept?

Tags: grammar

Today, this question came to my mind when I started cerebrating about what it actually is.

My conclusion is that: Te-form is simply another name for the concept of 連用形＋て(助詞) that native Japanese speakers would use or they were being taught this way, right?

And in accordance with that, the te-form usage should be roughly equal to or a part of て-usage, Could this line of thinking get through or it's just nonsense?

Comment: Related: [Does "te-form" of a verb always include て/で? Why?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36310/5010) It's indeed a Japanese-for-foreign-learners grammar term.

Comment: "cerebrating" xD

Comment: That last paragraph completely loses me -- _"the te-form usage should be roughly equal to or a part of て-usage"_.  No idea what that's supposed to mean?

Comment: You're just asking if the same concept is being taught differently to natives and foreigners, right? That's pretty common. If you look at native grammar materials and second language instruction materials you'll usually find different frames of reference. Natives and non-natives need different things from their grammar education.

Comment: It means as we are learning how to use te-form, we are actually learning how to use te-joshi as listed here: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6 @EiríkrÚtlendi

Comment: Very informative. Many thanks. @naruto

Comment: I'm just wondering about something about the Japanese language.  But it looks like It's the only language that a new system of grammar was invented when teaching to non-native speakers :) @Leebo

Comment: @HuFellan I'm saying that it's not the only language with that kind of difference. I teach English in Japan, and the way they explain grammar is not the same as how I learned English grammar in school. I think that's normal. They frame things in different ways, since the needs are different. I imagine with thousands of other languages out there I know nothing about, there might be other examples as well.

Comment: Natives don’t need to be taught 飲む becomes 飲んで. We know it before we learn about such abstract concepts as 連用形. Non-native learners, on the other hand, need to memorize the rules for those irregular forms. It helps to have a name to refer to the whole of 飲んで when it comes to teaching them, instead of explaining it as 連用形 plus て or sometimes で.

Comment: And ordinary native speakers don’t even recognize this て as a particle. It’s just part of the verb.

Comment: @aguijonazo, I'm honestly surprised to see it listed in dictionaries as 接続助詞 and not as 助動詞.  A 助詞 seems more like a discrete thing, like は or に or を, whereas 助動詞 are more like suffixes (which often inflect themselves) that must be attached to verbs, and also where the verbs must be in specific conjugational forms.

Comment: I can't grasp this post. Is the question about "who invented te-form" or "difference between te-form and 連用形+て"?