# In Japanese, what does the word "kimashita" mean and how does it work?

Tags: meaning

In my text book it says “`kimashita`” is the past form of “to come”.

But then in the textbook it says:

```
How long have you worked here?
Koko de wa dorekurai hataraite kimashita ka?
```

How does “`kimashita`” mean “`come`” in this context?

In this [question/answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B) it says that `-ていく (te iku)` and `-てくる (te kuru)` mean a change in state. That would explain the use of **te** in hatarai**te**, but I am not sure how the information in that question/answer relates to the use of `kimashita` in the example phrase (in the textbook kimashita is described as meaning the past form of `to come`. What does `came` having to do with `working`?)

Comment: I think your question is answered on the question linked (in the yellow box). If you want to explain how your question is different, please edit your question.

Comment: Yes, *hatarai**te kimashita*** is of this form. And of course, it is not only of this form, but also is exactly relevant to your question.

Comment: *kimashita* is the *masu* (polite) form of *kuru* in the past tense.

Comment: @Earthliŋ So does that mean kimashita doesn't mean come? I don't really understand. thanks in advance!

Comment: @big_smile No it does not mean "to come." Please *edit your question* and describe why the linked question did not help you. Then we can reopen this. If you cannot read hiragana or don't know how to form past tense, please say so in the question.

Comment: @naruto I have updated my question

Comment: @big_smile Great, I voted to reopen this.

Comment: We do something similar in English, too: "How did it come to be like this?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Japanese, there is something called *a subsidiary verb*. Read this first: [What is a subsidiary verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010)

A subsidiary verb is similar to English `have to` as in "I have to swim" and `be going to` as in "I'm going to swim". See how these `have` and `go` have lost their original meanings.

来る (kuru) on its own means "to come", but as a subsidiary verb (i.e., after the te-form of another verb), it means something different. As a subsidiary verb, くる (kuru) is usually written with hiragana, and it typically describes:

- an action/state which has been kept/continued/repeated until now
- a gradual state change over time up until now
- a physical movement toward the speaker

くる in 働いてくる (hataraite kuru) is used in the first sense above. In this case, you can translate it either simply as "have worked", or explicitly as "have kept working".

Another example:

> 試験に向けて、まじめに英語を勉強して**きた**。
>   Shiken ni mukete, majime ni eigo o benkyo shite **kita**.
>   Toward the examination, I have kept studying English seriously.

Kimashita is the past tense of kimasu, which is the polite (a.k.a. masu) form of kuru.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes  -ていく (te iku) and -てくる (te kuru)  express "Aspect" of time.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect

-ていく (te iku) is from Present to Future. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39413

-てくる (te kuru) is from Past to Present.

> How long have you worked here? 
>   Koko de wa dorekurai hataraite kimashita ka?

Here きました has nothihg to do with physical movement, and it is 100% expressing "Aspect" of time.

> ここでは、どれくらい働いてきましたか？

This question is asking:  How long have you worked here (from Past to Present in time) to reach NOW ( this point in time ) ?

But the answer doesn't have to be specially-tailored for time.  The question is no different from the usual [present perfect] form in English :

> How long have you worked here?